# Android application remove admob

Tags: android, admob

I bought an Android application code from codecanyon, but have almost no previous experience with Android Studio.

There is a admob code included already, and I would like to turn ads off. I contacted the developer and was told that turning off ads is a difficult process. He wants me to pay for modification.

Is it really that hard to turn off ads, or is he just wanting to rob me?

Comment: its simple. there is a xml element for showing ads remove that.

Comment: Remove the Admob dependencies from being compiled. Should then pop up a bunch of errors where the ad code is used, so go through and remove it

Comment: how do i identify that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's something you're going to need to learn Android Studio to do. Long story short, there might be either a JAR file that you remove or Gradle file that you edit.

Comment: he wants to rob you thats for sure